# Prevent a Child form from being dragged by means of the mouse

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the WndProc method that prevents dragging the main form.
I would like to prevent dragging a child form, created within the Form_Main constructor:

```
Form form1 = new Form();
```

The method to prevent from dragging the main form is:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Prevents Form_Main and any of the controls from being dragged by means of the mouse.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="messsage"></param>
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
        int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
        int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
        int HTCAPTION = 0x02;
        int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

        if (message.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND && message.WParam.ToInt32() == SC_MOVE)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (message.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN && message.WParam.ToInt32() == HTCAPTION)
        {
            return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref message);
    }
```

Please help.
Thank yoiu in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way (In my idea) and i'm not sure that it's the best way :

Make a class with name LockedForm :

```
 public class LockedForm : Form
 {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
        {
            int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
            int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
            int HTCAPTION = 0x02;
            int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

            if (message.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND && message.WParam.ToInt32() == SC_MOVE)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (message.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN && message.WParam.ToInt32() == HTCAPTION)
            {
                return;
            }

            base.WndProc(ref message);
        }
 }
```

And inherit your forms from this class, just like this :

```
public partial class Frm_Main : LockedForm
{
        public Frm_Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }       
}
```

And

```
Form form1 = new LockedForm();
```